# Pydicom with Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pydicom, streamlit

I wrote a code in streamlit with pydicom and published in heroku. So I got the error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbP4d.png)

My code is below:

```
import streamlit as st
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pydicom import dcmread
import zipfile
import io

def dicom_file(filename, file):
    st.write(filename)
    dataset = dcmread(file) <==LINE ERROR
```

Anybody have a idea?

Comment: Please provide the callstack as text, instead of an image (which also cuts off part of it).

Comment: Also, why don't you just use `filename` in `dcmread`? What is `file`?